# addClass to last item of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this function that gives me all the numbers from `1` to `870`. How can I get the `870` (the last item) and add a Class to it?

Thanks in advance.

```js
var points = new Array(870);
for (var i = 0; i < 870; i++){points[i] = i + 1;}
$(".numbers").html(points.join(', '))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=numbers></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `span` element and a custom class to it to the last point.

For dynamic array use `point.length-1` instead `869`

```js
var points = new Array(870);
for (var i = 0; i < 870; i++){points[i] = i + 1;}
points[points.length-1] = '<span class="custom-class">'+points[points.length-1]+'</span>'
$(".numbers").html(points.join(', '))
```

```css
.custom-class{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=numbers></div>
```

Comment: Hardcoding the index for the last element isn't a good practice. Use `points[points.length-1]` instead

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is use the `:last-child` selector on the `numbers` class, and add it that way like so:

```js
var points = new Array(870);
for (var i = 0; i < 870; i++) {
  points[i] = `<span>${i + 1}</span>`
}
$(".numbers").html(points.join(' '))
  .find(':last-child')
  .addClass('myClass')
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="numbers"></div>
```

Comment: Weirdly is not the last child but the number right before it

Comment: What do you mean? it is highlighting the last span in the div

Comment: It isn't 870 because I didn't add the `i + 1`. I will add it like you have.